# Discordance between component state and its props

Tags: reactjs

I am making a basic drag and drop utility where you can drag and recombine the position of three cards in React.

I dont know why but there seems to be discordance between the actual data on the parents state and its child. After some refactoring following users input, things are as this:

```
  onDrop = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    const newData = this.props.getDraggedCard(); //gets the data actually being dragged around
   let  receiverCard = Object.assign({}, this.state) //backup of the previous state

    this.setState({
        _id: newData._id,
        text: newData.text,
        title: newData.title,
        subtitle: newData.subtitle,
        image: newData.image
    }, () => { this.props.onDropParentData(receiverCard) })


}
```

this function is on every child component, which are the items actually to be moved around.

The parent component, which stores and saves the data:

```
onDropParentData = (receiverCard) => {

let {slideInformation}=this.state;  //the state where all the data is
let draggedCard = this.state.draggedCard; //the data being dragged

const indexDragged= slideInformation.findIndex((element)=>element.id===draggedCard.id)

const indexReceiver= slideInformation.findIndex((element)=>element.id===receiverCard.id)

let draggedCardIdStorage = this.state.draggedCard.id;

draggedCard.id = receiverCard.id;
receiverCard.id = draggedCardIdStorage;

slideInformation.splice(indexDragged,1,draggedCard);
slideInformation.splice(indexReceiver,1,receiverCard);

this.setState({slideInformation});
```

}

with this actual code, the state holds the correct information but when dragging and dropping, items dont switch between positions as desired, only the dropped item gets its new position.

The render method on the parent is:

```
  {this.state.slideInformation.map((slide,index) => {

            return (
              <CardFormBody

                getDraggedCard={this.getDraggedCard}
                key={index}
                onDropParentData={this.onDropParentData}
                onDrag={this.onDrag}
                slide={slide}
                onDragOver={this.onDragOver}

                setFormData={this.setFormData}

              />
            )
          })}
```

And every CardFormBody is

```
  <div draggable onDrag={(event) => { this.props.onDrag(event, this.state) }} className="newsCard" name={this.state.id}>
            <label>Título</label>
            <input name={this.state.id} onChange={this.handleTitleChange} value={this.props.slide.title} />
            <label>Subtítulo</label>
            <input name={this.state.id} onChange={this.handleSubtitleChange} value={this.state.subtitle} />
            <label>Texto</label>
            <textarea onDragOver={this.props.onDragOver} onDrop={this.onDrop} name={this.state.id} onChange={this.handleTextChange} value={this.state.text} />
            <button type="button" name={this.state.id} onClick={this.handleImgChange}>Añadir Imagen</button>
            <div className="imageWrapperForm">
                <img alt="preview" name={this.state.id} className="previewImg" src={this.state.image} />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, can you provide more code? How you pass data from child to parent? Anyway I think the misalignment between children and parent data could be on how you pass them.

Comment: Of course. The code excerpt here is from the parent component. This onDrag function is passed along the corresponding data to every child like this:

Comment: {this.state.slideInformation.map((slide) => {

                return (
                  <CardFormBody

                    key={slide.id}
                    onDrop={this.onDrop}
                    onDrag={this.onDrag}
                    slide={slide}
                    onDragOver={this.onDragOver}

                    setFormData={this.setFormData}

                  />
                )
              })}

Comment: Yes @CarlaAgulló you found the clue. Your problem is how you pass data between parent and children. Maybe you could modify logic like this: manage the drop event on child (with his local state) and  then pass data to store to the parent (so the parent has just to call `this.setState(data_from_child_moved)`).

Comment: I understand! Will give this a try and see if it works. thanks! :-)

Comment: Looks like now the state to be saved and sent back to the server is correctly set up but now the UI does not work even tough this.setState is invoked on the parent component when the new data is set up

Comment: Ok, I'm imagine that now you are managing some values on child state and some others values on parent state. Maybe you have to align these values in order to keep coherence between children components and parent. I know this comment is soo generic but what do you think to share more code by editing you question? Just the logic. I could work better.

Comment: yes,I did not want to put toooo much code on the question because it demotivates people to answer it. Ill edit the question with the code as it is now. Thank you

Comment: Well, I see your code and thank you to update it. Unfortunately now I'm in a bad moment at work and I can't spent more time to check it. May I suggest to take a look at existing solutions for drag and dropping? I found [this library](https://reactjsexample.com/sortable-and-resizable-pane-component-for-react/) if you want a fast solution. If you want to go deeper, reading some code to see a possible solution [this](https://reactjsexample.com/drag-drop-grid-layout-in-react-2/) could be intersting. Ciao :)

Comment: Well, I managed to do it!! it involved cleaning a lot of code and specially enforcing a ComponentWillReceiveprops to make sure  a change of state on the children, setting state with the received props so the child has the actual information too as well as the general state

Comment: Brava! Never give up with code! Sorry if I didn't help you so much... State managment between children and parent are always very complicated. So complicated that, in order to have a Global state manager I always use [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) in my react projects. If you have time, take a look, it's very powerful. ByeBye :)